# C++ win32 Api resource file

Tags: c++, api, winapi

i am learning win32 api . i know how to add pushbutton on the fly. now i am trying to add a pushbutton using a resource file ( rse.rc ) . below is my res.rc file defination:

```
IDB_B1 PUSHBUTTON "TOGGLE",7 , 20, 180, 200, 30
```

and i have evn generated a resource.h file to be included in the source. now the problem i am facing is how d i add this button to my main window ? i have tried adding cursor and icon using .rc file which is easy  but can not get my head around this button .

i guess it has to be under:

```
WM_CREATE:
```

but how exactly to call it from .rc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work this way.

Resources in Win32 are used to create many things: menus, accelerators and dialogs, among others; but not single controls.

What you want to do, a main window with a button can be achieved using two techniques:

1. Let your main window be a dialog. You write the resource for a full dialog, with buttons and all, and from `WinMain()` you call `CreateDialog()`. `DialogBox()` or similar.
2. Your main window is a normal window, and you create child contros manually. These controls are created calling `CreateWindowEx()` directly, with class name `WC_BUTTON`, as a response to `WM_CREATE` as you guessed.

Also, you can make the dialog a child of the main window, but I don't recommend that, specially if you are still learning.

Comment: first of all thanks for answering, the thing is i know the 2nd method thats how i have been doing it , but its a tediou s task when lots of controls are required so i learnt that we could achieve the similar thing using script files which are nothing but the resource files . can you provide an example ( or an appropriate link) of  first method that is by using dialogboxes

Comment: @user3521918: Do you mean the 1st method? The classic [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588(v=vs.85).aspx) is quite good. Also there are plenty of examples out there. Anyway, if you are just fighting tediousness, you can write an array of coordinates in code and call `CreateWindowEx()` in a loop.